# How to serialize message from kafka topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, axon

i use axon with mongodb and kafka.
i recieved issue.

how to solve this?

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException
cause-message       : org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
class               : java.util.HashMap
required-type       : java.util.HashMap
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
path                : /org.axonframework.extensions.kafka.eventhandling.consumer.streamable.KafkaTrackingToken/positions/m/entry/org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
line number         : 1
class[1]            : java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
required-type[1]    : java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : org.axonframework.extensions.kafka.eventhandling.consumer.streamable.KafkaTrackingToken
required-type[2]    : org.axonframework.extensions.kafka.eventhandling.consumer.streamable.KafkaTrackingToken
version             : 1.4.18
-------------------------------
```

and if i use this

```
axon:
  serializer:
    general: jackson
    events: jackson
    messages: jackson
```

change error to org.axonframework.serialization.SerializationException: Error while deserializing object

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely facing this issue, @newoneim, because you are using a more recent version of Java.

Recently some CVEs were found in XStream, requiring it to change its approach to serializing.
Previously, it simply de-/serialized everything by reflection, assuming it had the freedom to read everything, now you need to tell XStream which classes it can check through reflection.

[This](https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/axon-framework-release-4-5-4/3636) post from AxonIQ's forum explains this predicament in more detail.

Now, what can you do to solve it?
Well, using the `JacksonSerializer` would be a simple step.
Weirdly enough, I would expect that your configuration would've picked up that you have set the `JacksonSerializer` for all serializers.

My hunch is that the combination of the Mongo and Kafka Extension from Axon Framework doesn't correctly set the `JacksonSerializer` on your `MongoTokenStore`. Note that this is a hunch as we're missing the entire stack trace. However, it's the `TokenStore` dealing with `TrackingTokens`. And, it are the `KafkaTrackingTokens` that fail to serialize properly.

Note that the Mongo Extension from Axon Framework *does not* have a Spring Boot Auto Configuration. Thus, the settings you're using in your `application.properties` file aren't automatically picked up by any of the Mongo-extension-specific classes you built. Unless you're wiring them yourself, that is.